# Why does my pattern match fail in Scala?

Tags: scala

My method is as follows

```
  protected override def onEvent(event: Class[_]) = event match {
    case event: mydomain.Quote => println("qu")
    case _ => println("eventsample" + event)

  }
```

The console prints out the following

```
eventsampleclass mydomain.Quote
```

I thought this would have been caught in the pattern match

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no match, as your pattern is looking for an instance of Quote and your are passing `classOf[Quote]`, which is an instance of `Class[Quote]`, not a `Quote`.

To match, you would jave to call `onEvent(new myDomain.Quote(...))`, not `onEvent(classOf[myDomain.Quote])`. (It is somewhat unfortunate that the compiler accepts your first pattern, as it has no chance to match with event of type `Class`).

If you want to recognize class[Quote], you can use pattern `case c if c == ClassOf[Quote]`, but I don't see any reason not to do that with a simple `if`/ `else`